# User Accessibility on Field Via Apex Code (Not for Logged In user )

Tags: apex, accessibilty

Anyone knows how to check in apex if the user has access to the 'OwnerId' field of any selected object.
The user could be any and not only a logged-in user.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please see [ask] and make an [edit] to add any information.

Comment: Adding more information about your _overall objective_ may also help. This is an unusual objective that may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), if what you're really wanting is, for example, the ability to transfer a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query on [UserFieldAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_userfieldaccess.htm)

Obtain the Id of the user regardless if he is logged-in or not. Obtain the DurableId first

```
SELECT Durableid FROM UserFieldAccess WHERE FieldDefinition.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Account'
        AND FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Name'
        AND User.Id='<userId for the user you want to check field access for>'
```

Use the unique DurableId returned above to query UserFieldAccess.

```
SELECT DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,Id,IsAccessible,IsCreatable,IsUpdatable,UserId FROM UserFieldAccess WHERE DurableId = '<DurableId returned in query 1>'
```

Replace Account Name with OwnerId or any other field that you want to check the access for

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Running the query for any user, including my self, via apex seems to return an internal server error `List<UserFieldAccess> ufas = [SELECT IsAccessible FROM UserFieldAccess WHERE FieldDefinition.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Account' AND FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Name' AND UserId = :userInfo.getuserId()];`

Comment: Not to mention that the documentation that you linked to explicity says "Represents the access that the current user has to a field"

Comment: For the second query, enable Tooling API to avoid the internal server error

Answer (score 0):

You could query the User Profile and the assigned Permission sets and search for the highest permission on the Owner field.

Comment: Welcome to the community, can you provide an example in code of the solution you propose? Have you tested the solution to see if it actually works?